# Criando função decendio

Tags: python

Estou tentando criar uma função que me retorne os decendio algo como na figura:[image: decendio em Excel]

essa é a formula condicional em excel: `=SE(SE(OU(O3=1;O3=11;O3=21);P2+1;P2)=37;1;SE(OU(O3=1;O3=11;O3=21);P2+1;P2))`

E esse é o código que estou tentando fazer:

```
def decendio (var):
    if dia.all()==1:
        decendio=1
    
    elif dia.all()==11:
        decendio=2
    
    elif dia.all()==21:
        decendio=3

return(decendio)
```

entende-se por dencendio períodos de 10 dias iniciando a partir do dia 1 até o dia 10 temos o decendio 1, do dia 11 ao dia 20, decendio 2, do dia 21 ao dia 31 ou do dia 21 ao dia 30, ou do dia 21 ao dia 29 ( no caso de fevereiro) temos o decendio 3.

Então durante o ano teremos 36 decendios, logo essa conta em uma serie histórica deverá retorna o decendio 1 sempre que se iniciar um novo ano.

Answer (score 1):

Montei uma proposta de solução para o seu problema.

### Função Decêndio

Creio que você escolheu um caminho adequado, criar uma função que calcule o decêndio. E para essa função, o melhor argumento de entrada é da **data (date)** e a melhor variável de saída, um **número inteiro que represente o decêndio (n_decendio)**.

```
def decendio(date):
    day = date.day
    month = date.month
    
    if day >= 21:
        index = 3
        n_decendio = month * index + (month * 0 - 0)
        
    elif day >= 11:
        index = 2
        n_decendio = month * index + (month * 1 - 1)
        
    else:
        index = 1
        n_decendio = month * index + (month * 2 - 2)
    
    return n_decendio
```

Dependendo do dia do mês existe a forma correta de calcular o decêndio. Por exemplo, se o dia é maior ou igual a 21, bastaria multiplicar o mês pelo index, neste caso 3. Mas para você acompanhar a lógica de formação, mantive a expressão aditiva (month * 0 - 0), totalmente dispensável, expressão que acompanha as outras condicionais com as devidas variações.

### Testando a Função

Como dito anteriormente, o argumento de entrada é uma data, assim usaremos uma biblioteca padrão do python, a **datetime**, e desta biblioteca utilizaremos o objeto **date**, onde você deve passar dia, mês e ano. Segue exemplo de utilização:

```
import datetime

#Aproveitando a função today de datetime.date para avaliarmos qual decêndio é hoje (31/03/2019)
today = datetime.date.today()
today

#saída
datetime.date(2019, 3, 31) #64 nunca mais.

n_decendio = decendio(today)
n_decendio

#saída
9

#Você também pode avaliar uma nova data dessa forma, passando dia, mês e ano.
other_date = datetime.date(year=1987, month=12, day=1)
n_decendio = decendio(other_date)
n_decendio

#saída
34
```

### (Bônus) Otimizando a Função Decêndio

Um boa prática em python como em qualquer outra linguagem é realizar o que chamamos de controle de exceção, ou seja, avaliar e controlar possíveis bugs. Na função que criamos, precisamos que o argumento de entrada da função seja um objeto do tipo date. Teríamos problemas se passassemos uma data desta forma: '2019-03-31'. Assim, usamos o recurso de controle de fluxo: try/except/else.

```
def new_decendio(date):
    try:
        #Avalia se o argumento date NÂO é do tipo datetime.date, levantando um erro.
        if not isinstance(date, datetime.date):
            raise Exception('TypeError: date is not a datetime.date type.')
    
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: ' + str(e))
        return None
        
    else:
        day = date.day
        month = date.month

        if day >= 21:
            index = 3
            n_decendio = month * index

        elif day >= 11:
            index = 2
            n_decendio = month * index + (month - 1)

        else:
            index = 1
            n_decendio = month * index + (month * 2 - 2)

        return n_decendio
```

Em try avaliamos se date NÃO é um objeto do tipo datetime.date, caso não seja levantamos um erro que é capturado pelo except, caso seja, continuamos o fluxo em else.

### Último Teste

Vamos testar nossa otimização.

```
n_decendio = new_decendio('2019-05-14')
n_decendio

#saída
Error: TypeError: date is not a datetime.date type.

n_decendio = new_decendio(today)
n_decendio

#saída
9
```

### Conclusão

Encapsular códigos que vão ser reutilizados muitas vezes em funções é uma ótima ideia, mas não se esqueça controlar exceções e documentar o seu código (não realizado aqui). Você poderia escolher usar diretamente o dia e o mês como argumentos para a sua função, desta forma **def decendio(day, month)** e trabalhar com estas variáveis da mesma forma. Mas eu particularmente prefiro datetime.date pois vem com baterias inclusas para manipulação de data, caso você precise realizar algum tipo de operação. Para mais info da biblioteca datetime, segue [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).